# Change selected <option> of a <select> using ng-click

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-click, angular-ngmodel

I'm wondering how i can change the selected `<option>` of a `<select>` using ng-click.

```
            <select ng-model="orderProp">
                <option value="name">Alphabetical</option>
                <option value="age">Newest</option>
            </select>

            <a href="" ng-click="orderProp=name">order</a>
```

Can this be done like in the example above?

thx,

Comment: Is there a reason you are not using [ngOptions](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngOptions)?

Comment: *"Can this be done like in the example above?"*. Yes it can, did you try it?

Comment: yes, i tried it like in the example but it didn't work

Comment: When i click on the link it's adding an extra <option> to the select: <option value="? undefined:undefined ?"></option>

Comment: Because in your example `name` is a variable. Just make it a string `'name'`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done using two ways, either call a function on click of the anchor or just set the value `'name'` as a string.

1) http://jsfiddle.net/HB7LU/10717/ here you can directly set the string `'name'` on ng-click

2) Or this, http://jsfiddle.net/HB7LU/10718/

```
 <a href="" ng-click="fun()">order</a>
 $scope.fun=function(){
         $scope.orderProp= 'name'
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

The below code seems to be working. Please check if that is what is required. What I have added is the single quotes surrounding 'name' in anchor tag.

```
<select ng-model="orderProp">
    <option value="name">Alphabetical</option>
    <option value="age">Newest</option>
</select>

<a href="" ng-click="orderProp='name'">order</a>
```